# Font icons 1 or 2 pixels too high

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm making a paging control for a grid, and using font awesome icons for prev, next buttons.

The issue is that the icon (and any text that is in that element) appear 1 or two pixels higher than text where the font icon classes are not defined.  Other font libraries such as https://icomoon.io appear to have the same behavior.

In the image below, you can see how the image and it's text do not align well vertically with the page numbers.  Setting vertical-align styles on the element or pseudo element do not seem to help as none of the vertical alignment settings gives aligns perfectly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it an alignment problem or a size problem?

Comment: try to control the `line-height`

Comment: line-height and font-size are the same for all elements and the icon pseudo elements

Comment: Even if I change the font sizes to larger fonts, it's always 1 or two pixels off.  But because there are borders I can't just set the margin-top because then the borders look different for some buttons and not others

Comment: Hey Jeremy, if you show us some code it might be easier than having us guess which attribute you have or haven't used. 

Post some code here and possibly a codepen if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and found the solution on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825183/font-awesome-menu-icon-has-1px-offset) and adding this to my css fixed it for me.
Don't forget to put the good associated icon (mine was `fa-lock`) and the good `content` value

```
.fa-lock:before {
  content: "\f023"; /*This is what the creator of font-awesome put in to show the lines character */
  display:block;
  margin-top:-1px;
}
```